# Descend/resolve user-space C function code down to kernel-space at compile time?

Tags: c, linux

I may not be able to come back to this question immediately, but I thought I'd jot it down now that I've encountered it:

First of, I'm not sure what the proper way to call this is; I've tried "descend" and "resolve" in the title, but I'd like to know if there is a more proper term. In essence, what I'd like is to obtain something like shown on this image I got from [Kernel System Calls - ar.linux.it](http://www.ar.linux.it/docs/ksys/):

[image: ksys-figure1]

Here is a more concrete example - consider the following small and non-working (<sub>it will simply cause an "Assertion failed"</sub>), but compilable ALSA code:

```
// atest.c

#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

static snd_pcm_t *playbck_pcm_handle;
static char wrsrcbuf[256] = {[0 ... 255] = 5}; // initialization gcc specific
static snd_pcm_uframes_t period_frames = 32;
static int ret;

int main() {

  ret = snd_pcm_writei(playbck_pcm_handle, wrsrcbuf, period_frames);

  return 0;

}
```

I can build this with:

```
gcc -Wall -g atest.c -lasound -o atest
```

... and then, I can observe assembly with `objdump`:

```
$ objdump -d -M intel -S atest
...
int main() {
 ...

  ret = snd_pcm_writei(playbck_pcm_handle, wrsrcbuf, period_frames);
 804842d:       8b 15 40 a1 04 08       mov    edx,DWORD PTR ds:0x804a140
 ...
 8048447:       e8 0c ff ff ff          call   8048358 <snd_pcm_writei@plt>
 ...

  return 0;
 8048451:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0

}
...
```

... and this tells me only that a subroutine `<snd_pcm_writei@plt>` will be called - but it doesn't tell me in, say, which library object file (sidenote: given compilation passed, would that mean that `gcc` would know about the location of the library as an object file on the current system?)

Then, I can in principle run the program (though not this one), and by using the built-in Linux tracing (`ftrace`) functionality in `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace`, obtain a run-time kernel log. Due to the preemptive nature and scheduling of the kernel, one cannot really count on any constancy in order of execution, but in principle, we could get something like this (<sub>not from the above example though, as it doesn't do any proper device initialization</sub>):

```
sys_ioctl() {
  ...
  do_vfs_ioctl() {
    snd_pcm_playback_ioctl() {
      snd_pcm_playback_ioctl1() {
        _cond_resched();
        copy_from_user() {
          ...
        }
        snd_pcm_lib_write() {
          snd_pcm_lib_write1() {
            _raw_read_lock_irq();
            _raw_spin_lock();
            snd_pcm_update_hw_ptr() {
              snd_pcm_update_hw_ptr0() {
                azx_pcm_pointer() {
                ...
```

So, this tells me that in response to the `snd_pcm_writei` command - ultimately `sys_ioctl` -> `snd_pcm_playback_ioctl` -> `snd_pcm_lib_write` will be called, which would be ALSA functions built into the kernel; however, also functions like `azx_pcm_pointer()` will be called, which are part of a device driver (<sub>`azx_pcm_pointer` is part of the `hda-intel` driver</sub>).

So my question is - is there an application that could output the function "descent" tree of a program from userspace to kernel space - either at compile-time (which would be `gcc` itself, but with some special switches if they exist for that purpose), or post-compile (like when using `objdump`, which is however not "runtime", as the analyzed program itself is not running)? E.g. for this example, I'd hope for an output like:

```
int main() {  # atest
  ...
  ret = snd_pcm_writei(playbck_pcm_handle, wrsrcbuf, period_frames);  # atest
  ...
    <snd_pcm_writei@plt> # libasound.so ??
    ...
      sys_ioctl() {  # ???.(k)o?
      ...
        snd_pcm_playback_ioctl() { # ???.(k)o?
        ...
          azx_pcm_pointer() { # /lib/modules/.../sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko
        ...
      ...
```

I understand that the code could take a number of code paths - so hopefully this tool would be able to resolve them all - or allow for setting of variables, to limit the number of code paths; but in general, the output would be a tree (which could then be visualized with, say, `graphviz`).

I also understand that resolving drivers may not be possible without going into runtime (since a device - and its driver - could be specified at runtime by, say, command line arguments of the user-space program); but I'd hope at least for a notification telling me something like "Here an unspecified driver function would be called".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sidenote: given compilation passed, would that mean that gcc would know about the location of the library as an object file on the current system?

Yes, this is exactly why you have to specify -lasound. This function was found by linker. If for some reasons libasound don't have it - you'll get linking error.

> So my question is - is there an application that could output the function "descent" tree of a program from userspace to kernel space

None of i've heard of. It is surely possible, but transition between user and kernel spaces are far from mere function call. In fact, userspace library using syscall() function, which sets appropriate system call number and parameters to registers and issuing special CPU interrupt, which kernel catches and then executes - so neither gcc nor any object code parsing tools can trace this transition. My best guess is dumping both user and kernel spaces and connecting this logs afterwards, but it would be tricky.

Why do you want this, by the way?

Comment: Many thanks for that @keltar - explains why this kind of a tool would be difficult to write... I need it because in my study of ALSA, I got surprised quite a bit about how things actually end up working on kernel level, even neglecting things as pre-empting; so I'd like this kind of a tool for study purposes - to basically show me, in a more readable format, what sequence of commands should I expect in principle. Cheers!